# array value not return on my table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here I am trying to use navigation controller with UISegmentController..I have used here switch case for three different tabs. On tapped it
should change private public and protected but can see value which
is declared in array.

```
    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var mySegmentControll: UISegmentedControl!

    var privateList:[String] = ["Private Item 1","Private Item 2"]
    var protected:[String] = ["Protected 1","protected 2"]
    var publicList:[String] = [" public 1","Public 2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self;
        myTableView.dataSource = self;
    }
```

My code can't return cell1 I don't have any error but I can't see output my my array.

```
    @IBAction func refreshbtn(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    }

    @IBAction func mySegmentValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var retunValue = 0

        switch (mySegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex){
        case 1 :
            retunValue = privateList.count
            break
        case 2:
            retunValue = publicList.count
            break
        case 3:
            retunValue = protected.count
            break
        default :
            break
        }
        return retunValue
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        switch (mySegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex){
        case 1:
            cell1.textLabel!.text = privateList[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 2:
            cell1.textLabel!.text = publicList[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 3:
            cell1.textLabel!.text = protected[indexPath.row]
            break
        default :
            cell1.textLabel?.text = "Boat"
            break
        }
        //cell.petname.text
        return cell1
    }
}
```

Comment: add self.tableView.reloadData() in mySegmentValueChanged

Comment: What's the `retunValue` returned in `numberOfRowsInSection`? Your segmentedControlled doesn't start at 0 and not 1 ? Also `mySegmentValueChanged` doesn't do anything like reloading the data.

Comment: You don't need break's in your switch cases, Swift switch cases are non-cascading.

Comment: thanks its works @Miknash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var retunValue = 0

    switch (mySegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 1 :
        retunValue = privateList.count
        break
    case 2:
        retunValue = publicList.count
        break
    case 3:
        retunValue = protected.count
        break
    default :
          retunValue = 1;// use this
        break
    }
    return retunValue
}
```